# Can a normal user execute "shutdown now" successfully?

Tags: centos, shutdown

```
$shutdown
Must be root.
$ shutdown -h
Must be root.
$ shutdown now
```

The system shutdown with 'shutdown now' command. I thought it need to have root privilege to shutdown the system or doing it using sudo, am I wrong?

Comment: It happen at CentOS 7, which I know it is now using systemd, the shutdown command is a symbolic link to systemctl, but I not very sure is it behave properly.

Comment: Consider asking your question over at http://superuser.com, since SO is dedicated to programming questions.